# Strange, small boxes, that appears after editing e-mail in Gmail

Tags: gmail

If I compose an e-mail in Gmail, then save it, and re-open this draft again, I can see small, empty boxes. I can't remove them. What is this? Is this some kind of virus?

I've checked and verified this issue on two different computers, using two different Gmail accounts.

Comment: Small boxes where? I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: @majumdar - Post a screenshot.  Probably not a virus.  Viruses do nasty stuff to your computer, not cause tiny rendering issues in your web browser.  Trust me, you'd know if you had a virus.

Comment: @majumdar This is not the same issue but does it look anything like this? http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/53476/what-are-these-squares-when-i-paste-on-gmail

Answer (score 2):

Can you try by changing your text area from plain text to rich text or viceversa, also can you check you gmail account under another webbrowser. If still you are finding the issue you can contact GMAIL directly [image]

Comment: @Mit - I wouldn't tell him to contact Google until he knows what's going on.  It could be his computer, his browser, a conflicting Firefox/Chrome/IE add-on.  The first step is for the OP to post a screenshot.