# What are these squares when I paste on Gmail?

Tags: gmail

When I paste anything on Gmail these two little squares will show up:

[image]

Looks like two characters, I can cut them as I can do with any text, but when I paste there's nothing to paste. Any idea what this is?

By the way, I use Boomerang for Gmail, not sure if it's related.

**--update:**

It shows up always in the end of the mail, after the signature, even if I paste something in the beginning of the text.

Comment: That's odd. Do you see them when you paste anywhere else?

Comment: @Krampus not, only on GMail.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment, but I remember having a similar issue about a year ago.
I'm curious, does it happen to you only when using a specific browser?

Comment: @Imray looks like it's only on Firefox... Not happen on Chrome.

Comment: My guess is they should be unicode characters something like end-of-line and such..

Comment: @Aditya it shows up always in the end of the mail, after the signature, even if I paste something in the beginning of the text.

Comment: @Aditya I mean, it's added to the end of the mail, not pasted with my text.

Comment: Tom, you say it only happens in Firefox and not Chrome.  Is Boomerang installed with Chrome?  Also, a key point is that the extra "text" always appears at the bottom of the message no matter where you paste text....even if there is text already present between the bottom and where you paste.   Are the characters present in the e-mail After you send?

Comment: @TomBrito do you have any installed extensions you think may affect what you copy or paste in Firefox? Try to update your browser and plugins (like flash player).

Comment: @KevanSheridan no, Boomerang is not installed on Chrome, it's probably the cause... Also, the characters are not present after send...

Comment: I think the issue is finally identified.  Boomerang may be using some special characters to keep track of messages.  When you copy / paste with Boomerang installed, they appear in your pasted-to message.  The fact that they do NOT appear in the results of sent messages mean you probably only see during the short paste phase of sending mail. Hopefully the folks working on Boomerang can sort this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was indeed an issue with Boomerang on Firefox.

Thanks to Michael Hoffman for letting us know about the issue. We released a fix for this last week. If you are still seeing this, make sure you have the latest version and reload Gmail after clearing cache.

Answer (score 2):

Try cutting the 2 dots and pasting them into the online hex editor at http://www.edithex.com/ and then click the **Convert** button.

Then copy and paste the results here.

I’m guessing the 2 dots are control characters, such as EOL, or EOF but we should be able to work out what they represent, when you paste the hex codes for the characters here.

Comment: I have this problem too. I pasted an X on either side of the two little squares. When I paste into edithex.com, I get only XX (58 58). The squares are missing.

Comment: I can cut, but there's nothing when I paste...

Answer (score 2):

I remember something like this when I was using Boomerang for Gmail in the Chrome Browser but I can't remember the details. I agree, might be control characters.

What happens when you try this on a computer without Boomerang installed?

Trying it without Boomerang might eliminate that as a culprit.

Other things to check:

- Is the latest version of Boomerang installed?
- Are there other extensions or plugins installed that might be conflicting?

I no longer use Boomerang or I would test it again.

Comment: I had this problem too on Firefox. Just disabled Boomerang and the problem went away.

Comment: Still not sure what's the meaning of those dots/squares, but it really looks like Boomerang's stuff anyway.

Comment: Baydin, the makers of Boomerang, say they are looking into it. https://twitter.com/baydin/status/419644359970013187

Comment: [Baydin posted an answer here](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/54408) to follow-up.

Comment: Glad to hear this is now fixed. Boomerang is a great tool for that missing "manage this email later" feature. More useful than you might first guess.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the signature text of your account in Settings.

Also check in "Labs" tab of settings if you have enabled any unnecessary apps.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like it's an attempt to attach an image to your email body

Comment: Can you reproduce that for us?